# Datatable only first row receives jquery var

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

Only the first row in my data table receives my var sel.

The var is given values from a html dropdown. If you click the print button on the first row the var is passed to the url. If you change the select options the var is updated.

If you click any other row the var comes across as undefined.

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function datatableHandler ( sel)
                    {
                        $('#workorder').DataTable().destroy();

                        var table = $('#workorder').DataTable({
                            //display columns
                            "columns": [
                                //display action buttons
                                {"mData": "idWorkOrder",
                                    "mRender": function (data,  type,  row) {
                                        return  '<a href="print.php?idWorkOrder='+row.idWorkOrder+'&pages='+sel+'" data-toggle="tooltip" title="PRINT" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>'+
                                            '<a href=update.php?idWorkOrder='+row.idWorkOrder+' data-toggle="tooltip" title="EDIT"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>'+
                                            '<a href=delete.php?idWorkOrder='+row.idWorkOrder+' data-toggle="tooltip" title="DELETE"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>';
                                    }
                                },
                                {"data": "cFirstName"},
                                {"data": "cLastName"},
                                {"data": "wRoofContract", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )},
                                {"data": "wSidingContract", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )},
                                {"data": "wGutterContract", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )}
                            ],
                            "processing": true,
                            "serverSide": true,
                            "responsive": true,
                            "ajax": {
                                url: 'datatables.php',
                                type: 'POST'
                            }
                        });
                        table.draw( false );
                    }
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#multipleSelect').on('change', function() {
                            sel = $(this).val();
                            console.log(sel);

                            datatableHandler (sel);
                        });
                        $('#workorder').DataTable().destroy();

                        var table = $('#workorder').DataTable({
                            //display columns
                            "columns": [
                                //display action buttons
                                {"mData": "idWorkOrder",
                                    "mRender": function (data,  type,  row) {
                                    sel=1;
                                        return  '<a href="print.php?idWorkOrder='+row.idWorkOrder+'&pages='+sel+'" data-toggle="tooltip" title="PRINT" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>'+
                                            '<a href=update.php?idWorkOrder='+row.idWorkOrder+' data-toggle="tooltip" title="EDIT"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>'+
                                            '<a href=delete.php?idWorkOrder='+row.idWorkOrder+' data-toggle="tooltip" title="DELETE"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>';
                                    }
                                },
                                {"data": "cFirstName"},
                                {"data": "cLastName"},
                                {"data": "wRoofContract", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )},
                                {"data": "wSidingContract", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )},
                                {"data": "wGutterContract", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )}
                            ],
                            "processing": true,
                            "serverSide": true,
                            "responsive": true,
                            "ajax": {
                                url: 'datatables.php',
                                type: 'POST'
                            }
                        });
                        table.draw( false );

                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your datatable function on change event so that datatable will get updated value of sel.

I have just call the datatableHandler function  on change event of multi select and pass value sel to that function.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">


            function datatableHandler (var sel) {
// destroy the datatable

 $('#workorder').DataTable().destroy();

          var table = $('#workorder').DataTable({
                            //display columns
                            "columns": [
                                //display action buttons
                                {"mData": "idWorkOrder",
                                    "mRender": function (data,  type,  row) {
                                    return  '<a href="print.php?idWorkOrder='+row.idWorkOrder+'&pages='+sel+'" data-toggle="tooltip" title="PRINT" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>'+
                                            '<a href=update.php?idWorkOrder='+row.idWorkOrder+' data-toggle="tooltip" title="EDIT"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>'+
                                            '<a href=delete.php?idWorkOrder='+row.idWorkOrder+' data-toggle="tooltip" title="DELETE"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>';
                                    }
                                },
                                {"data": "cFirstName"},
                                {"data": "cLastName"},
                                {"data": "wRoofContract", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )},
                                {"data": "wSidingContract", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )},
                                {"data": "wGutterContract", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )}
                            ],
                            "processing": true,
                            "serverSide": true,
                            "responsive": true,
                            "ajax": {
                                url: 'datatables.php',
                                type: 'POST'
                                }
                        });
                        table.draw( false );
                    };     

             $(document).ready(function () {
                            var sel;
                            $('#multipleSelect').on('change', function() {
                               sel = $(this).val();
                                console.log(sel);

                               //call datatable handler function with value sel
                                 datatableHandler(sel);
                            });
                  });
    </script>
```

Comment: Ok, you are awsome i've been working on this for a week. Everything works except for the fact that the table is not displayed until a selection is made from the dropdown. However the sel value is passed correctly.

Comment: Ok so this appears to work. Any suggestions? updated code above.

Comment: @NicholasRoeder Thank you. datatableHandler(sel);  you can call this function document ready so that it can show you the datatable.

Comment: Yeah, I added datatableHandler(sel) outside the onchange function and it works great. Thanks.

Comment: Had to add
                            
sel=$('#multipleSelect').val();
datatableHandler (sel);